# How can I count the number of elements in a list tree in Racket?

Tags: sql, racket

I am going over some racket exercises, and one of these exercises asks to create a function called "count-trees" that will count all the elements in a ListTree. Per the instructions, a ListTree is a recursive data structure with the following definition(s):

-It can be an integer

-It can be a list or a list with sublists

-Per the instructions, we assume that a list tree can never be empty

Here are a few examples of what a List Tree looks like:

```
(list 1 2)

(list (list 1)
       2
      (list 1 4 5))

(list 1
       (list 2 1)
        1
        1)
```

Now, here is what my code looks like:

```
(define count-tree (lambda (lst)
                   (if (empty? lst)
                       0
                       (length (lst)))))
```

When I execute the function, it works but only when there is one list, not on lists that contain sub-lists. It seems to only count how many lists there are, but I want it to count all elements in the list. Is there a way to go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Length can be implemented like this:

```
(define length 
  (lambda (lst)
    (if (empty? lst)
        0
        (+ 1 (length (cdr lst))))))
```

And thus:

```
(length '((1 2) (3 4))) 
; ==> 2
```

Since the list has two elements. It doesn't bother it that the two elements are two lists that also has elements and your function needs to do that. Thus your function need to do one more thing than `length` does. You need to sum the recursion of the `car` and the `cdr` in the event you have a pair in the `car`, otherwise the same as `length`.

There are more clever versions of `length` but I guess you'll learn about that later.